# How to store information to properly display multiple images that makeup a single game character/object/NPC?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

*Sorry for the confusing title, I wasn't too sure on how to word it.*

I'm just getting into 2D game development after recently discovering the power of HTML5's Canvas element. I'm on my first basic project to learn the ropes. This game will allow players to join a game, and basically fight on a single map with tanks. The more kills they get, the more higher-tier tanks they can unlock and use.

But, I'm sort of stuck on how to draw the tanks into the game *(properly, at least).* Each tank has three images: the body of the tank, the turret, and a tank shell that will be drawn to the game when the tank fires. Of course, when the game loads a tank, it needs to know the correct location to put these images. All tanks have different size, therefore I simply cannot tell the game to load the body and turret in the same spots every time. When the body of the tank is drawn to the canvas, the turret of course needs to be drawn relative to this corresponding body.

So how should I store this info? Do I put a hardcoded object in the code that contains a list of turret offsets for each individual tank?

**I hope I explained my problem clearly. Please ask if you have any questions. :)**

Comment: Either a list of turrent offsets for each individual tank *size*, or you just store it as a property on the tank itself, next to its size attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by "Store it as a property on the tank itself?" Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Store it where you store the sizes, types etc of your tank objects. Maybe you should show some of your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way to deal with multiple sized sprites is to define each sprite position using its centerpoint rather than as its usual top-left corner.**

That way the size of each the tank is irrelevant when positioning it.

To implement centerpoint positioning, you can:

- translate to the desired position on the map
- and then drawImage with an offset of -width/2 and -height/2.

**An example,**

Assume your tankBase sprite is 38px wide and 59px high.

Then to draw the tankBase centered at x/y==[100,100] you can do this:

```
ctx.translate(100,100);
ctx.drawImage(tankBase,-38/2,-59/2);
```

Here's a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/V9uEr/

Comment: If I have to use `restore` and `save` for each frame, won't that be really resource intensive?

Comment: In production you can substitute translate(-x,-y) or even pure math for save/restore.

Comment: Here's an updated demo that uses tank objects to store info about tankBase & tankTurret positions.  It also uses negative transforms instead of save/restore to undo transforms.  You probably want to rotate the turret, but if you don't need rotations you could do all transform in pure math format.  Note: canvas transforms can be blazing fast because they are GPU accelerated when a GPU is available.  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4ctVh/  Good luck with your learning project!